# Angular ng-class and expression

Tags: angularjs

In a `ng-class` directive I have an expression calling a scope method with argument in curly brackets. If the variable is initialized in the controller (in which the element with ng-class is placed) the argument is good, but if it later changes, when the scope method is called it will be called with the old value of the variable. [Here is a plunker for better understanding of my problem.](http://plnkr.co/edit/qZTJWsqlsTNi8NcK9py3?p=preview) Why is this happening and how can I fix it.

P.S. Thanks for the suggestions, and yes, you are right but I have forgotten to add a detail for my case. I can't just pass the variable since it is a part of a string with other stuff in it. [Here is an updated plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/qZTJWsqlsTNi8NcK9py3?p=preview)

Update: I fixed my problem using ui-router and its `ui-sref` and `ui-sref-active` directives. But thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use the curly braces.

```
<div ng-class="{active:isActive(val)}"></div>
```

Or according to your update:

```
<div ng-class="{active:isActive('prefix/'+val)}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do `ng-class="{active:isActive(val)}"`

[**Plunk**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vea4yWUv6rzL6ygnxOCM?p=preview)

EDIT:

Try with `ng-class="{active:isActive('prefix/' + val)}"`

Comment: @Nikolay I updated the answer. Honestly I do not know Angular enough yet to explain why the interpolation doesn't re-evaluate, but I will have a look.

Comment: Thanks, but still I don't wanna do that since in my case would do code duplication, so violating the DRY principle.

Comment: @Nikolay How come the concatenation would lead to code duplication while the interpolation would not?

Comment: In the application I'm building it would since I'm reusing the string for both a ling to a page AND for calling the isActive method. It is really because of the way I have built my application framework, but I can't show it in a simple example.